# Cascading CSS for multiple classes

Tags: html, css

I have a basis class `.media` for my divs and there are styles I want to give to all `.book` and some styles (background images) are only valid for different other classes:

```css
div.media {
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 100%;
}

div.media.book {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/10");
}

div.media.movie {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/10");
}

div.media.movie-old {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/10");
}

div.mediatext {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  top: 2px;
}

div.media:hover {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="media book">
  <div class="mediatext">
    clockwork orange
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media movie-old">
  <div class="mediatext">
    blade runner
  </div>
</div>
```

but the hover does not work. I imagine to be able to define one parent class, have multiple subclasses with the different bg-images in it and have one extra element for `:hover { filter: invert(1); }` that affects all that has class `media` in it (so text and images get inverted).

Comment: I updated your question with your code in a runnable snippet and put in some placeholder images (and made the divs a little bit larger), so we could test it - and it appears to be working as expected. Is there something else in your code that's overriding the `hover` state?

Comment: I guess you are right. I tried to simplify the question and maybe the error arose from me trying to make it too fancy :( Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you forgot to add an equal after the `class` keyword:

```html
<div class="media book">
    <div class="mediatext">
        clockwork orange
    </div>
</div>
<div class="media movie-old">
    <div class="mediatext">
        blade runner
    </div>
</div>
```

TIP: Try to debug with F12 open and [inspecting elements](https://support.google.com/campaignmanager/answer/2828688#zippy=%2Cuse-cases) to see which classes and styles are applied to them.

Comment: you are technically right, but this was just a stupid copy&paste error. it still does not work.

Comment: @xtlc your example does work for me: https://i.ibb.co/c3vTsbc/chrome-XPERpvnb-Qm.gif EDIT: Oh, I've seen the comment above. I guess you should try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and you'll find the problem yourself for sure. Btw, check for the F12 developer tools to see which styles your elements have. With developer tools you can even fake mouse states on them, like hover, and see which styles are applied to them when hovering and which classes apply those styles.